# Div positioning inside a table

Tags: html, css

I have a website, and I want to add a picture up in the top right corner (well 100 margin from the top and right).

I have all my content inside a table (I already know this is bad).

Here is the question: How can I position a DIV at exact the place I want, and without the table taking up the "gap" of the DIV.

For instance, if I have a table, and I place a DIV inside it and position it relatively, the amount of space the DIV "WOULD" have taken up is still taken up in the table column. Why?

How can I fix this?

Absolute positioning outside the table?

The table align is set to center, so I think absolute positioning wouldn't work outside the table...

Thanks

Comment: Yes I do... IE6 must work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wont get into the fact that you should probably recode your page...

Put the `div` outside the table so that `body` is the `div`s parent. Then when you absolutely position it it will be positioned relative to the body...

```
#id_of_div { position:absolute; top: 100px; right: 100px; }
```

Comment: Will this always put the div in the same correct place, regardless of screen resolution?

Comment: it will put it 100px from the top right on any resolution. this is what i thought you wanted.

Comment: @Camran: Yes. Absolute positioning takes the element outside of normal document flow and places it in an exact spot. If `<body>` is the parent of your `<div>`, then it will *always* be placed 100px from the top of the viewport, and 100px from its right edge. Whether or not this is what you want for you to determine, but it will always be there.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the table cell to `position:relative;`, then you can have the div as `position:absolute;` with the `left` and `top` as they were before.

Although, last time I tried this Firefox didn't like it, and I had to put a `<div>` inside the table cell first and have THAT as the relative-position block.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of that gap may not be possible.  You can't control the positioning of cell elements besides the basic css for tables that is available: http://w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_td.asp

Can you convert the area to use a table-less design?  I'm sure you can get plenty of help on how to do it on here :-)